# How API Rate limits works in giphy?

Tags: giphy, giphy-api

I'm using `giphy` API for get `GIF` stickers but I'm kind of confusion with `giphy` API guide on rate limiting mention over here:

https://developers.giphy.com/docs/#response-codes

I will get 429(Response Code) when my API key rate limits exceed. I have to manage 429 HTTP status code.
But I don't know, how many request I can in `giphy` API for demo mode and production mode?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First for you, Would you please confirm if you've applied for a production key and got approval from giphy team?

Meanwhile, the rate limit for production key vs the testing/beta key is different :

- **testing/beta key**: `1000 reqs / day`
- **production (need apply + approval)**: `50,000 reqs / day, 21,000 reqs / hour`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can you link to source?  I do not see in their docs a mention of the rate limit

Comment: Check https://developers.giphy.com/faq/ , But Now, Rate limit changed. :(

Comment: As of today, according to the faq (search for "beta") - the rate limit is now 100. From the response "These beta keys are rate limited to a maximum of 100 API calls an hour".